# C++ windows form : how to control user input format in a textbox?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am using C++ windows form application, I would like to limit a user input to a certain format only.

for example, I would like user to input phone number in the format xxx-xxxxxxx only, the application should prompt an error message if the input wasn't in this format.

How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated. :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Regex.IsMatch(txtPhone.Text, @"{yourRegexForPhoneFormat}")`